# Capitalise first letter of every sentence

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, capitalization

How do I capitalise the first letter of every sentence in a string? Should I use `.capitalisedString`?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432452/how-to-capitalize-the-first-word-of-the-sentence-in-objective-c/24712107#24712107

Comment: @MaxMacLeod: Not a 100% duplicate. The referenced thread shows how to capitalize the first character of a string, not of each *sentence* in the string.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod No. Pay attention that this is about string with multiple sentences. Not just one string.

Comment: ok I see it now point taken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enumerate `String` per sentences by using `NSStringEnumerationOptions.BySentences`. But it detect a "sentence" only if the first character is upper-cased.

So, This may not be perfect, but you can try this:

```
import Foundation

let text:String = "lorem ipsum dolor elit, sed aliqfuas. imfs enim ad veniam, quis nostrud consequat? duis aute irure dolor in pariatur."

var result = ""
text.uppercaseString.enumerateSubstringsInRange(text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, options: .BySentences) { (_, range, _, _) in
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ enumerate all upper cased string

    var substring = text[range] // retrieve substring from original string

    let first = substring.removeAtIndex(substring.startIndex)
    result += String(first).uppercaseString + substring
}

// result -> "Lorem ipsum dolor elit, sed aliqfuas. Imfs enim ad veniam, quis nostrud consequat? Duis aute irure dolor in pariatur."
```

Comment: It capitalises the first letter in the string, but the others at the beginning of the sentence are still lowercase.

Comment: (+1), but: Why `var _`? – The last two lines can be simplified slightly to `result += String(first).uppercaseString + substring` .

Comment: There is actually a subtle problem here. Your method applied to `"toeﬂ. abc."` yields `"Toeﬂ. aBc."`. The reason is that the *ligature* "ﬂ", when converted to upper case, becomes two characters: "FL" :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "this is.a good boy";
    String[] dot = a.split("\\.");
    int i = 0;
    String output = "";
    while (i < dot.length) {
        dot[i] = String.valueOf(dot[i].charAt(0)).toUpperCase()
                + dot[i].substring(1);
        output = output + dot[i] + ".";
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Did you see that the question is about the Swift programming language?