# How to capitalize first word in every sentence with Swift

Tags: swift, nsstring

By taking into account of user locale, how can I capitalize the first word of each sentence in a paragraph? What I want to achieve is no matter the case inside the sentence, the first letter of each word will be uppercase and the rest will be lowercase. I can do only one sentence by first converting everything to lower case, then get first letter and make uppercase and finally add them up together. My question is different than [How to capitalize each word in a string using Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261218) since I don't want to capitalize each word. I just want to capitalize the first word of each sentence. `capitalizedString` turns

```
"this is first sentence. this is second sentence."
```

to

```
"This Is First Sentence. This Is Second Sentence."
```

What I want is

```
"This is first sentence. This is second sentence."
```

My question is also different than [Capitalise first letter of every sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169581/capitalise-first-letter-of-every-sentence) Since @rintaro's code doesn't work on my below example. It keeps capital letters in original text intact. With @rintaro's code;

before

```
"someSentenceWith UTF text İŞğĞ. anotherSentenceğüÜğ"
```

after

```
"SomeSentenceWith UTF text İŞğĞ. AnotherSentenceğüÜğ."
```

What I want to achieve,

```
"Somesentencewith utf text işğğ. Anothersentenceğüüğ."
```

My code below can only do partial conversion.

```
var description = "someSentenceWith UTF text İŞğĞ. anotherSentenceğüÜğ"
description = description.lowercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())
let first = description.startIndex
let rest = advance(first,1)..<description.endIndex
let capitalised = description[first...first].uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale()) + description[rest]
```

I will really appreciate if you can please read my question carefully, since this is the third time I am editing the question. I am really sorry if I couldn't ask it clearly since I am not a native speaker. So even though @rintaro answered similar question, his answer doesn't solve my problem. @martin-r suggests a Objective-C answer which again doesn't solve the problem I have. There were another user eric something who also suggested another answer but deleted afterwards. I just can't understand why several people suggest different answer which doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I have reopened the question. I admit that I overlooked the *"and the rest will be lowercase"* part (which was not apparent from the initial examples) and apologize.

Comment: It seems to me that a tiny modification of rintaro's code should give your intended result:  Just replace `result += String(first).uppercaseString + substring` by `result += String(first).uppercaseString + substring.lowercaseString`.

Comment: I am really disappointed by your actions sir. You gave/approved wrong answers multiple times, locked the question for being a duplicate. Of course they are deleted now so I can't prove any of those things. Anyway, what should I do next time so that I won't take the shovel into my throat next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions to achieve this. I'm adding this function as a String extension so it will be trivial to call in the future:

```
extension String {

    func toUppercaseAtSentenceBoundary() -> String {
        var string = self.lowercaseString

        var capacity = string.utf16Count
        var mutable = NSMutableString(capacity: capacity)
        mutable.appendString(string)

        var error: NSError?

        if let regex = NSRegularExpression(
            pattern: "(?:^|\\b\\.[ ]*)(\\p{Ll})",
            options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.AnchorsMatchLines,
            error: &error
            ) {

            if let results = regex.matchesInString(
                string,
                options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros,
                range: NSMakeRange(0, capacity)
                ) as? [NSTextCheckingResult] {

                    for result in results {
                        let numRanges = result.numberOfRanges
                        if numRanges >= 1 {
                            for i in 1..<numRanges {
                                let range = result.rangeAtIndex(i)
                                let substring = mutable.substringWithRange(range)
                                mutable.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withString: substring.uppercaseString)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        return mutable
    }
}

var string = "someSentenceWith UTF text İŞğĞ. anotherSentenceğüÜğ.".toUppercaseAtSentenceBoundary()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out. I was very stressed out due to behavior of some people in here.

Comment: Thank you, but it must be "(?:^|\\b(\\.|\\!|\\?)[ ]*)(\\p{Ll})" to match any punctuation, just not a period.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
let str = "someSentenceWith UTF text İŞğĞ. anotherSentenceğüÜğ"

var result = ""
str.uppercaseString.enumerateSubstringsInRange(indices(str), options: .BySentences) { (sub, _, _, _)  in
    result += sub[sub.startIndex ... sub.startIndex]
    result += sub[sub.startIndex.successor() ..< sub.endIndex].lowercaseString
}

println(result) // -> "Somesentencewith utf text i̇şğğ. Anothersentenceğüüğ"
```

---

ADDED: Swift2

```
let str = "someSentenceWith UTF text İŞğĞ. anotherSentenceğüÜğ"

var result = ""
str.uppercaseString.enumerateSubstringsInRange(str.characters.indices, options: .BySentences) { (sub, _, _, _)  in
    result += String(sub!.characters.prefix(1))
    result += String(sub!.characters.dropFirst(1)).lowercaseString
}

print(result)
```

Comment: rintaro, are you so kind to update your answer for Swift 3?

Answer (score 2):

Updating @rintaro's code for Swift 3:

```
let str = "someSentenceWith UTF text İŞğĞ. anotherSentenceğüÜğ"

var result = ""
str.uppercased().enumerateSubstrings(in: str.startIndex..<str.endIndex, options: .bySentences) { (sub, _, _, _)  in
    result += String(sub!.characters.prefix(1))
    result += String(sub!.characters.dropFirst(1)).lowercased()
}

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this extension in Swift 5 according to @Katy's code

extension String {

```
var toUppercaseAtSentenceBoundary: String {
    
    var result = ""
    self.enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .bySentences) { sub, _, _, _  in
        result += String(sub!.prefix(1)).uppercased()
        result += String(sub!.dropFirst(1)).lowercased()
    }
    
    return result
}
```

}

How to use:

```
let string = "This is First sentence. This is second Sentence.".toUppercaseAtSentenceBoundary 
print(string) /* Output: "This is first sentence. This is second sentence." */
```

Comment: the `.characters` no longer used, just delete that part for latest swift