# How to capitalize first word in every sentence with Swift 3?

Tags: xcode, string, swift3

I would like to capitalize the first word of every sentence in a string. For example this string:

> apple Park will run one of the largest on-site solar energy
>   installations in the world. it is also the site of the world’s largest
>   naturally ventilated building.

Should become:

> Apple Park will run one of the largest on-site solar energy
>   installations in the world. It is also the site of the world’s largest
>   naturally ventilated building.

I also would like that the capitalization don't happens when a world already has a capital letter among its characters, for example:

> iPad is a mobile device.

Remains

> iPad is a mobile device.

For the first part of this task, I could use this code by [rintaro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283003/how-to-capitalize-first-word-in-every-sentence-with-swift):

```
let str = "someSentenceWith UTF text İŞğĞ. anotherSentenceğüÜğ"

var result = ""
str.uppercaseString.enumerateSubstringsInRange(str.characters.indices, options: .BySentences) { (sub, _, _, _)  in
    result += String(sub!.characters.prefix(1))
    result += String(sub!.characters.dropFirst(1)).lowercaseString
}

print(result)
```

But its for Swift 2 and don't work for Swift 3.

Comment: @JamesWebster haha you got it .

Comment: Just convert your Swift 2 code to Swift 3 code and it will work (the docs will give you the new method names) - well it will work as well as it did in Swift 2 (in each sentence it uppercases the first letter and lowercases the rest, potentially losing uppercase letters within a sentence), but you can address that if required by improving the algorithm. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

Each sentence is iterated. For the first word in each sentence, if it contains a capital letter, nothing changes, otherwise, it is capitalized and the rest of the sentence is appended to the result.

```
let str = "this is a sentence without a brand named tablet. this too is a sentence but with iPad in it! iPad at start of sentence here?"
var result = ""

//Iterate each sentence
str.uppercased().enumerateSubstrings(in: str.startIndex ..< str.endIndex, options: .bySentences) { substring, range, _, _ in

    var original = str.substring(with: range)

    var capitalize = true

    //Iterate each word in the sentence
    substring!.enumerateSubstrings(in: substring!.startIndex ..< substring!.endIndex, options: .byWords) { word, wordRange , _ , stop in

        var originalWord = original.substring(with: wordRange)

        //If there is a capital letter in that word, don't capitalize it
        for character in originalWord.characters {
            if String(character).uppercased().characters.first == character {
                capitalize = false
                break
            }
        }

        //But always stop after the first word. It's the only one of concern
        stop = true
    }


    //Modify the first word if needed
    if capitalize {
        result += String(original.characters.prefix(1)).uppercased()
        result += String(original.characters.dropFirst(1))
    }
    else {
        result += original
    }

}
print(result)
```

outputs:

> This is a sentence without a brand named tablet. This too is a sentence but with iPad in it! iPad at start of sentence here?

NB. I didn't focus on efficiency here. If you are going to use this for a large amount of data, you may want to profile it first!

### Note

I don't think the `.bySentences` option is very robust. During my testing, I accidentally had two spaces in one of the sentences and it failed to parse properly. I've also just tried with your example "Apple..." sentences and it only finds one.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't actually work. Try changing your "THIS" to "this" and you'll see it fails. Note the original's use of `uppercaseString`, but it also munges more than the initial letters so it doesn't work properly either.

Comment: I think this is part of the problem with `.bySentences` I mention. It seems it's actually using the capital letter as a marker for a new sentence. Are your sentences only ever in English? Perhaps you could look for sentence end markers ([.?!, etc]) for the sentence parsing bit

Comment: Yes it is using the initial capital letter as part of its sentence recognition, which is why the original solution contains uppercase & lowercase conversions.

Comment: @CRD. I'll have another go!

Comment: @CRD, I've updated and this appears to work. It uses an uppercase string for the comparisons, but pulls values from the original where necessary.

Comment: It works fine. Next step could be to find way to avoid it to make lowercase even the words with capital letters within a word thas is not in the start of a sentence. For example in: "new AAAS president emphasizes making the case for science". But it was not part of my question so that's okay. You did a great job thanks!

Comment: @Tel, I've amended. It should no longer lowercase the rest of the string! :)

Comment: James - Good, you saved me adding an answer ;-)